# jQuery - get the index of a element with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this one:

```
<li> .... </li>
<li> .... </li>
<li> .... </li>
<li class="active"> .... </li>
<li> .... </li>
```

I want to find out the index (number in the list) of the item with the "active" class element.
in this case the index would be 4 (or 3 if we're starting from 0)
How can I do that?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

With the [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) :

```
$('li.active').index()
```

Working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EcZZL/

Edit - added link to the api for `.index()` per Nick's advice

Comment: What if the selector is `$(this).hasClass("myClass")`? It doesn't have an index() function.

Comment: `var g = parseInt($('div.slideIsActive').index()) + 1;` gives me `1` but this `var index = $(this).find("div.slideIsActive").index() + 1;` gives me `0`. How can I edit to get `1` using the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 14):

Like this:

```
var index = $("ul li.active").index();
```

[`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) without parameters gives the index of the element with respect to it's siblings, which is what you want in this case.

Comment: Looks like I had the first cup of coffee this morning Nick ;)

Comment: @HurnsMobile - Indeed :) Make sure to give a link to the appropriate functions you're using if possible, helps future googlers...more so with `.index()` because it has several very different uses :)