# JQuery find nth child and display

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Using JQuery how do we find what the current nth:child the element being clicked is and alert that number.

```
$('.bouncetabs a').click(function(){
        alert($(this + ':nth-child'))
        return false
    });
```

Obviously that does not work. How do we do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - get the index of a element with a certain class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204349/jquery-get-the-index-of-a-element-with-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want the [.index method](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
var selector = '.bouncetabs a';

$(selector).click(function(){ 
  //just .index() may work too, depending on the html
  alert($(this).index(selector)); 
  return false;
});
```